# Can a Table get automatically filled if it only contains Foreign Keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

So I have the following 4 Tables in here: [SQL Fiddle with 4 Tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b71d5d)

I would like my 4th Table, Certificates to be automatically filled/updated since it doesn't have anything unique.
It just haves 3 Foreign Keys.

I want to be able to use that as a reference for linking my Tables with JOINs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tables are not filled "automatically" (except via triggers).  Use `insert` to insert rows.

Comment: And what would be the logic to fill that table? Any possible combination of the three FKs? If so - the table would contain one million entries if the other tables each contain (only) 100 rows.

Comment: Table 4 is a 100% duplicate of Table 3, therefore it can be eliminated.  There is something basic that you do not understand.  You can obtain the info you want (Table content without Table 4 existing) from Table 3 with a SELECT with JOINs.  Table 3 has the "links" already.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to duplicate data - but you can create a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html). Views allow you to save a select statement and treat the result as a table (when running a select statement, insert/update/delete is a different question).